# Why does DBIx::Class not create many-to-many accessors?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

While [creating a schema from a database](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Manual::Cookbook#Creating-Schemas-From-An-Existing-Database) many-to-many relationships between tables are not created.

Is this a principal problem?

Is it possible to detect from the table structure that many-to-many relationships exist and create the respective code in schema classes automagically?

Comment: It does, starting from [v0.07015](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RKITOVER/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader-0.07033/Changes) (released on 2011-12-09).

Comment: @eugeney: DBIx::Class developers are really wonderful. I talked about this and about another problem of mine with Caelum on their IRC channel and he had solutions for both of them. So now you could see them in live. Awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with developing this kind of code is that many tables that contain multiple references are not many-to-many tables, and have multiple references for other reasons.  For instance, I'll make up a schema for some fictional app where something could be regarded as a many-to-many table, when it is not.

```
create table category (
    id primary key,
    ...
);

create table sub_category (
    id primary key,
    category references category(id),
    ...
);

/* EDIT:
    This is the table that could be regarded as many_to_many
    by an automated system */
create table product (
    id primary key,
    category references category(id),
    sub_category references sub_category(id),
    ...
);
```

Something could be built this way for ease of use, without having to do multiple table joins in the database on a website, especially when considering speed.  It would be difficult for a piece of code to say definitively 'this is not a many_to_many' situation, while the developer should be able to easily figure it out, and add in the many_to_many line below the checksum.

I consider DBIX::Class schema outputs a good starting point, and little more, especially when working with auto numbering in non-MySQL databases, among other things.  I often need to modify above the "Don't modify above this line" stuff (although many_to_many can obviously go below that checksum, of course.

Comment: Yes, i thought on similar situation. But i  did not find out how in this situation may something go wrong, when there is many-to-many accessors? So accessor would be defined not by the meaning of data, but it doesn't break anything also. Or am i missing something?

Comment: It wouldn't cause any damage, but it would be incorrect.   As the system is now, when the default schema builds, it is not incorrect, just not 'complete'.  There is no requirement to use many_to_many connectors, and the system as it is now does not build them for that reason.  Adding them would add complexity and the possibility to be incorrect, so I would argue that leaving it out is the best option.

Comment: I think your answer deserves bounty. Still i  don't agree with it in every aspect. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: There is an open source community for developing the DBIx::Class functionality.  You might want to look into it to see what their interest is in some functionality like this, then add the code into the DBIC if they think that it is a good idea.  I personally think this should be a developer decision, but disagreements are what make the world an interesting place.  Thanks for the bounty.

Comment: Yes, i agree, it is my next step (discuss it with DBIC developers). I also agree it may still be as option not as default behavior.

Answer (score 5):

It is indeed a somewhat fundamental problem -- many_to_many is a "*relationship bridge*" and not a "*relation*."  The documentation explains that ["the difference between a bridge and a relationship is, that the bridge cannot be used to join tables in a search, instead its component relationships must be used."](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Glossary.pod#Relationship_bridge)

On the other hand, this means that if the real relationships are correctly discovered it should be straightforward to add the many-to-many relationships automatically: First, search for tables that have two or more `has_many` relationships.  Then, for each pair of such relationships, create a many-to-many relationship bridge.  (Of course, one might hope that DBIx::Class would do this itself.)